# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'sb_wisp' does not have a method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the woocommerce on my site. I am getting the following warning when I click on the order menu in woocommerce. Please let me know how can I fix it.

```
  Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'sb_wisp' does not have a method 'admin_column_content' in //html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 429
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check the admin_column_content is within the class or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you called the function outside the class name. . .

Here is my suggestion

```
class sb_wisp {

function admin_column_content() {

// Your Content Goes Here . . .

}

}

add_action("Your Hook", array('sb_wisp','admin_column_content'));
```

Try this one It should work :)